# Apt package broken ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt, dpkg, desktop-environments

I ran sudo apt update in terminal i got only 1 package which is update. i think my apt is broken.

```
sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

and when i run `dpkg --configure -a`

```
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up php7.0-mysql (7.0.4-7ubuntu2) ...
dpkg: error processing package php7.0-mysql (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 10
Setting up libpaper1:amd64 (1.1.24+nmu4ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing package libpaper1:amd64 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 10
Setting up gconf2-common (3.2.6-3ubuntu6) ...
dpkg: error processing package gconf2-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 10
Setting up ufw (0.35-0ubuntu2) ...
dpkg: error processing package ufw (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 10
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libpaper-utils:
 libpaper-utils depends on libpaper1; however:
  Package libpaper1:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libpaper-utils (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up php7.0-readline (7.0.4-7ubuntu2) ...
dpkg: error processing package php7.0-readline (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 10
Setting up php7.0-opcache (7.0.4-7ubuntu2) ...
dpkg: error processing package php7.0-opcache (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 10
Setting up php7.0-mbstring (7.0.4-7ubuntu2) ...
dpkg: error processing package php7.0-mbstring (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 10
Setting up grub-efi-amd64 (2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3) ...
dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 10
Setting up php7.0-curl (7.0.4-7ubuntu2) ...
dpkg: error processing package php7.0-curl (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 10
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of grub-efi:
 grub-efi depends on grub-efi-amd64 (= 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3); however:
  Package grub-efi-amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package grub-efi (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php-curl:
 php-curl depends on php7.0-curl; however:
  Package php7.0-curl is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php-curl (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 php7.0-mysql
 libpaper1:amd64
 gconf2-common
 ufw
 libpaper-utils
 php7.0-readline
 php7.0-opcache
 php7.0-mbstring
 grub-efi-amd64
 php7.0-curl
 grub-efi
 php-curl
```

Please give my any solution to resolve this issue. im unable to install any new package.

Comment: First how did we get here, then run `cat /etc/apt/source.list` and post it here...

Comment: Here is the sources.list 
cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security universe restricted multiverse main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates universe restricted multiverse main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main universe restricted multiverse

Comment: Please put it in your post

Comment: unable to edit post